# How would I use tensorflow to "add" two images?

Tags: python, image, tensorflow

I have two images (assume I know their filepaths, and can reach them). How would I "add" them together, so that the function returns an image that is essentially them next to each other, so basically image1+image2=image1image2, left to right.

Comment: If you use TensorFlow, `tf.concat(image1, image2, axis=width_axis)`; numpy also has concatenate function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you aren't restricted to TensorFlow, and that the images are the same size, as Richard said, you could use numpy concatenate function (as images are treated just like a normal matrix)

```
import numpy as np
stackedImg = np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=1) 
// Axis=1 for horizontal stacking and 0 for vertical
```

And if you want to test it out with open cv

```
import cv2
cv2.imwrite('output.png', stackedImg)
```